# wxpython : Unable to update Column

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am Using this code for updating my records on column, but i am not able to update 2nd and 3rd column.
I followed this [link](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/), it is working but not with my code.

```
        self.m_listCtrl3 = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LC_ALIGN_TOP|wx.LC_ICON|wx.LC_REPORT  )
    self.m_listCtrl3.InsertColumn( 0, "c1", width=-1)
    self.m_listCtrl3.InsertColumn( 1, "c2", width=-1)
    self.m_listCtrl3.InsertColumn( 2, "c3", width=-1)
    bSizer15.Add( self.m_listCtrl3, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

    self.m_listCtrl3.InsertStringItem(0,"Pankaj")
    self.m_listCtrl3.SetStringItem(0,1,"Somesh")
    self.m_listCtrl3.SetStringItem(0,1,"Punit")
```

The Output which i am getting is :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I got answer
i was using wx.LC_ICON style 

self.m_listCtrl3 = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LC_ALIGN_TOP|wx.LC_ICON|wx.LC_REPORT  )

but i removed that style and now code is working fine

self.m_listCtrl3 = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LC_ALIGN_TOP|wx.LC_REPORT )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking it to display in multiple formats.
Choose wx.LC_REPORT or wx.LC_ICON not both.
For your purposes here, you need wx.LC_REPORT

Also:

```
 self.m_listCtrl3.SetStringItem(0,1,"Punit")
```

should be

```
self.m_listCtrl3.SetStringItem(0,2,"Punit")
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine now. but what should i do if i want to add icon in first column.

Comment: Check out the code in the wxPython Demo package, ListCtrl demo, it's all there